# azure-synapse - Scala: Using MSI access token unable to retrieve data from Azure sql server db table

Tags: scala, azure-synapse

Linked services configured for sql db through System assigned identity as shown in below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o9KA.png)

Below find note book (in scala) in Azure synapse

```
  import com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary
  import java.util.Properties

   val jdbcHostname = ".sql.azuresynapse.net"
   val jdbcPort = 1433
   val jdbcDatabase = ""

   // Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
   val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

   // Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
   val connectionProperties = new Properties()

   // Driver that can also be observed in the log when using the 'native' Synapse SQL way.
   val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
   connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

   // Create a linked server to your dedicated pool with a Manged Identity
         connectionProperties.setProperty("accessToken",
    mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds("samplesqllink"))

     // Define your query
    val pushdown_query = "(select top 10 ID from dbo.tblEmployees) data_alias"
     **val df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query,         properties=connectionProperties)**
     display(df)
```

Here getting this error

```
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/
```

But with User name and password it is working fine.

Please help here did I miss anything

successfully it should return table data

Comment: Could you please check that linked service connection tested successfully or not?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code in my environment, successfully fetched using `username` and `password` but failed with connection string.

[image]

Below is the linked service with authentication `System Assigned Managed Identity`. Getting test connection failed.

[image]

Because you need to add user into your sql database.
copy the identity name, in my case it is jsynapse.
Login to SQL database as admin user and run below commands according to you environment.

```
CREATE  USER [jsynapse] FROM  EXTERNAL  PROVIDER;
ALTER  ROLE db_datawriter ADD  MEMBER [jsynapse];
ALTER  ROLE db_datareader ADD  MEMBER [jsynapse];
```

[image]

now test the connection.

[image]

Notebook output:

[image]

For more information refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#using-managed-service-identity-authentication) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for response.
SQL commands are successfully executed with AAD login user and it worked fine.